# Pages goes blank after converting posts to be dynamic on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

After making my WP posts dynamic on WordPress, the pages (located on the main menu) wouldn't display its contents anymore.

What files may have affected the page's not displaying correctly? Its just pure, white, blank pages now.

As for the blog posts files, here is some of the files I have touched:

Under

> /public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/

```
single.php
```

Under

> /public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/template-parts

```
content.php
content-single.php
```

Comment: It will be hard to pin point the problem without seeing any code or clarifying what was modified on the files. My guess is that `content.php` is used by the default `page.php` template and you broke something there or there is some kind of a fatal error ( if you don't have wp_debug on ) that prevents the output of the content.

Comment: Thank you so much @drip. Forgot to turn wp_debug on. Apparently its a syntax error on content-page.php. Hope you had answered the question instead of comment so I can rate is as the best answer